# Cannot get GPU to render Cycles but my CPU can - Why?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have a 2016 Macbook Pro with AMD Radeon Pro 450. In the system preferences of Blender I have the ‘Cycles Render Devices’ set to ‘Metal’ and ‘AMD Radeon Pro 450’ is checked. When I try to render, Blender freezes. I’ve tried to also place a checkmark by ‘Intel(R) Core i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz’ so both my GPU and my CPU is checked, but still the same result, Blender crashes. What’s weird though is if I uncheck my GPU and only have my CPU checked, Blender does not crash and renders just fine (though terribly slow). What can I do to get Blender to not crash while trying to render with my GPU so I don’t have to wait as long for renders? Just started learning Blender this week, so I’m extremely unfamiliar with everything still.

Linked answer is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: I know nothing about Macs but there's an article published last month [here](https://appleinsider.com/articles/22/03/10/blender-update-adds-support-for-metal-gpu-rendering-on-mac) which says that "Mac users wanting to take advantage of the new Metal rendering need to have a device running at least macOS Monterey 12.3 or later."

Comment: I am running 12.4. Do you know why my question just got closed? The answer that was linked is not at all a solution to my problem.

Comment: From that answer it sounds as if your graphics card may not be new enough to be supported or you may need to update your graphics driver but, as I said, I know nothing about Macs.